# How can I update this statement to be preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, deprecated

As the title states can someone indicate how I can correctly update this line of code is:

```
$payment_number = ereg_replace(" |-", "", @$_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number']);
```

to us the `preg_replace` correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for regular expressions! You can solve this using a simple [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$payment_number = str_replace(array(" ", "-"), "", @$_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number']);
```

In case you want to use regular expressions anyway, you only have to add the [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to make it PREG compatible:

```
$payment_number = preg_replace("/ |-/", "", @$_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number']);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, indeed a good answer +1 worked perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check isset a `$_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number']` first

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number'])) {
    $payment_number = preg_replace("/ |-/", "", $_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$payment_number = 0;

if(isset($_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number'])){  
    $payment_number = preg_replace('` |-`','', $_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number']);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answers the question it may be helpful to explain what you did and why you did it to help the asker understand it better.